# How to separate one html table, generated by database data, below itself if columns run off the page?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, tcpdf

Below is an HTML table that was generated systematically from a MySQL database and generated using TCPDF. Each column is generated based on the number of analyses that were input by the user. As the image shows, systematically creating the table becomes a problem once the columns become more than can fit on the page.

What I want to be able to do is only allow 4 columns to be generated and then append the corresponding results as shown, and then below the first table generate a second with the next 4 columns and so on.

Does anyone know of a simple way that this can be done?

If there is no simple way then manipulating the PHP code is the only option. I am not allowed to show the entire code (client's requirements), however, I can show the section that generates the columns.

The `$micro_analysis` is numbers separated by commas like: `1,2,3,4` which correspond to a primary key, that is the analysis name, from the table `microbiology_analysis_database`, just to add some clarity.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $sqla = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND sample_group='$group' AND $analysis!='';";
    $resulta = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);

    $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND sample_group='$group' AND $analysis!='';";
    $resultb = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlb);


    $micro_analysis = '';
    while($input = mysqli_fetch_array($resultb)) {
        $micro_analysis .= $input[$analysis] . ',';
    }

    $micro_analysis_arr = array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $micro_analysis)));

    $array_size = count($micro_analysis_arr);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resulta) > 0) {

        $html .= '
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">      
        <thead>
        <tr>';
        //<th><strong>Lab ID</strong></th>
        $html .= '<th width="200px"><strong>Client ID</strong></th>';

        foreach ($micro_analysis_arr as $row1) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM microbiology_analysis_database WHERE id=$row1 AND analysis_type='$analysis_type';"; 
            $resultc = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $inputc = mysqli_fetch_array($resultc);


            if (empty($inputc['analysis_sample_type'])) {
                $html .= '<th style="text-align:center;"><strong>'.$inputc['analysis_name'].'<br /> ('.$inputc['analysis_unit'].')</strong></th>';
            } else {
                $html .= '<th style="text-align:center;"><strong>'.$inputc['analysis_name'].'<br /> ('.$inputc['analysis_unit'].')</strong></th>';
            }
        }

        $html .= '
        </tr>                           
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)) {

                    $sam_id = $row['sample_id'];

                    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND $analysis!='' AND sample_group='$group' AND sample_id=$sam_id;";
                    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

                    $micro_analysis2 = '';

                    while($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                        $micro_analysis2 .= $input[$analysis] . ',';
                    }
                    $micro_analysis_arr_2 = array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $micro_analysis2)));


                    $html .= '
                    <tr>'; 
                //<td>'.$row['env_sam_id'].'</td>
                    $html .= '<td>'.$row['c_sam_id'].'</td>';

                    foreach ($table as $row2) {

                //if statement to select sample with corresponding analysis

                        if (!in_array($row2, $micro_analysis_arr_2)) {

                            $html .= '<td></td>';

                        } else {

                            $query5 = "SELECT * FROM results_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND sample_id=$sam_id AND m_analysis_id=$row2"; 
                            $result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $query5);
                            $input5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5);
                            $result_id = $input5['id']; 

                            $query6 = "SELECT * FROM analysis_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND m_analysis_id=$row2"; 
                            $result6 = mysqli_query($conn, $query6);
                            $input6 = mysqli_fetch_array($result6);
                            $step_10_progress = $input6['step_10_progress'];

                            if (empty($input5['result'])) {

                                $html .= '<td style="text-align:center;"><em>Analysis Pending</em></td>'; 

                            } else {

                                $html .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.htmlspecialchars($input5['result']).'</td>';

                            }                   
                        }
                    }

                    $html .= '</tr>';
                }       

                $html .= '</tbody></table>';
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Table]

Comment: @Dharman Thank you I am aware of this. The code is still in the development phase and part of my workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want use the [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function, and then loop through the resulting arrays, like so:

```
    $sqla = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND sample_group='$group' AND $analysis!='';";
    $resulta = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);

    $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND sample_group='$group' AND $analysis!='';";
    $resultb = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlb);


    $micro_analysis = '';
    while($input = mysqli_fetch_array($resultb)) {
        $micro_analysis .= $input[$analysis] . ',';
    }

    $micro_analysis_arr = array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $micro_analysis)));

    $array_size = count($micro_analysis_arr);

    // Chunk the array into smaller parts
    $tables = array_chunk($micro_analysis_arr, 4);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resulta) > 0) {

        // Loop through 4-part arrays as unique tables
        foreach($tables as $table) {

        $html .= '
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">      
        <thead>
        <tr>';
        //<th><strong>Lab ID</strong></th>
        $html .= '<th width="200px"><strong>Client ID</strong></th>';

        foreach ($table as $row1) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM microbiology_analysis_database WHERE id=$row1 AND analysis_type='$analysis_type';"; 
            $resultc = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $inputc = mysqli_fetch_array($resultc);


            if (empty($inputc['analysis_sample_type'])) {
                $html .= '<th style="text-align:center;"><strong>'.$inputc['analysis_name'].'<br /> ('.$inputc['analysis_unit'].')</strong></th>';
            } else {
                $html .= '<th style="text-align:center;"><strong>'.$inputc['analysis_name'].'<br /> ('.$inputc['analysis_unit'].')</strong></th>';
            }
        }

        $html .= '
        </tr>                           
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)) {

                    $sam_id = $row['sample_id'];

                    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND $analysis!='' AND sample_group='$group' AND sample_id=$sam_id;";
                    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

                    $micro_analysis2 = '';

                    while($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                        $micro_analysis2 .= $input[$analysis] . ',';
                    }
                    $micro_analysis_arr_2 = array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $micro_analysis2)));


                    $html .= '
                    <tr>'; 
                //<td>'.$row['env_sam_id'].'</td>
                    $html .= '<td>'.$row['c_sam_id'].'</td>';

                    foreach ($table as $row2) {

                //if statement to select sample with corresponding analysis

                        if (!in_array($row2, $micro_analysis_arr_2)) {

                            $html .= '<td></td>';

                        } else {

                            $query5 = "SELECT * FROM results_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND sample_id=$sam_id AND m_analysis_id=$row2"; 
                            $result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $query5);
                            $input5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5);
                            $result_id = $input5['id']; 

                            $query6 = "SELECT * FROM analysis_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND m_analysis_id=$row2"; 
                            $result6 = mysqli_query($conn, $query6);
                            $input6 = mysqli_fetch_array($result6);
                            $step_10_progress = $input6['step_10_progress'];

                            if (empty($input5['result'])) {

                                $html .= '<td style="text-align:center;"><em>Analysis Pending</em></td>'; 

                            } else {

                                $html .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.htmlspecialchars($input5['result']).'</td>';

                            }                   
                        }
                    }

                    $html .= '</tr>';
                }       

                $html .= '</tbody></table>';

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would I have to add the same foreach function for generating the result rows?

Comment: If I understand what you intend to do correctly, then no: let's say the $micro_analysis_arr array has 40 records in it. After the array_chunk, the resulting $tables array would consist of 10 arrays with 4 elements. After foreaching through the $tables array, you would have 10 tables, with 4 rows each.

Comment: The second table in my scenario does not produce the rows. Can I perhaps send you my code somehow to have a look?

Comment: I see now that you didn't include the tbody part in your code, that's probably where you want to use the foreach. It's a bit difficult to say how it should look without knowing the data structure, but if you post the entire section of this code, i can try to give a suggestion.

Comment: Andrew, please see the edit, I added the body with your preliminary changes. Also I agree about the queries, but that is a problem for another day haha!

Comment: Alright, I have updated my answer with the full code, but I'm not sure if it's going to work or not, since I have no way of testing it and I don't fully understand what's going on with $micro_analysis_arr_2 and such. In case it doesn't work, the key is still this: 1. Take the array that holds the table rows (which you want to maximize as four)... 2. Use array_chunk to create an array containing separate, smaller arrays. 3. Loop through this arrays, and for each iteration, create a table. Inside the table, for each row, loop through the current array's elements. Basically, a nested loop.